# Using two table and order results

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.like, COUNT(V.Id) as Count FROM des C, views V WHERE C.Id = V.Id_des order by C.like, Count DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Work fine to find the first best ID that contain lot of views and likes, but he display only one row ! i want it to display everything (**DES** Table) but from the one that have lot of views + likes to lowest one.

**DES** Table contain id, like, text, description, all item's informations (Want to display this rows depending on the views)

**VIEWS** Table contain each view on the item, each time user view it, we save id_des (DES) + ip address on it.

I made this too but same thing:

```
    SELECT 
        des.Id, 
        des.like, 
        COUNT(views.Id_des) as Count 
    FROM 
        des
        LEFT JOIN views ON views.Id_des = des.Id
    ORDER BY
        des.like, 
        Count DESC LIMIT 20
```

Waiting your help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add GROUP BY des.Id

```
SELECT 
    des.Id, 
    des.like, 
    COUNT(views.Id_des) as Count 
FROM 
    des
    LEFT JOIN views ON views.Id_des = des.Id
GROUP BY des.Id
ORDER BY
    des.like,
    Count DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Update for ordering by COUNT views lines + likes:

```
SELECT 
    des.Id, 
    des.like, 
    COUNT(views.Id_des) as Count, 
    des.like + COUNT(views.Id_des) as Count2
FROM 
    des
    LEFT JOIN views ON views.Id_des = des.Id
GROUP BY des.Id
ORDER BY
    Count2 DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution but this not helped me, the result are not ordered by VIEWS+LIKES.

Comment: Updated query - now it orders by count of views + value from column des.like, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you RESOLVED ! ur help very appreciated :)